# Posix Shell test non zero exit code script termination when set -e

Tags: shell, sh, posix, exit-code

Reading the manual of the `test` shell command:

```
man test
```

Description states:

> Exit with the status determined by EXPRESSION.

But this conflicts with my POSIX sh test script examples, where I use `set -eu` that should terminate a script if a command's exit status is not zero:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

status=1
test "$status" -ne 0 && echo "Status not eq 0"
echo "(A) Exit code for "$status" = $?"

echo ""

status=0
test "$status" -ne 0 && echo "Status not eq 0"
echo "(B) Exit code for "$status" = $?"

echo ""

status=1
test "$status" -ne 0
echo "(C) Exit code for "$status" = $?"

echo ""

status=0
test "$status" -ne 0
echo "(D) Exit code for "$status" = $?"
```

running that script provides the output:

```
Status not eq 0
(A) Exit code for 1 = 0

(B) Exit code for 0 = 1

(C) Exit code for 1 = 0
```

This is how I understand flow of a execution for:

```
status=1
test "$status" -ne 0 && echo "Status not eq 0"
echo "(A) Exit code for "$status" = $?"
```

with output:

```
Status not eq 0
(A) Exit code for 1 = 0
```

`test "$status" -ne 0` evaluates to true so its exit code is zero therefore an expression after boolean `&&` is executed and since it is just an `echo` it returns also zero exit code so the script does not brake and echoes next line `(A) Exit code for 1 = 0`

but for the

```
status=0
test "$status" -ne 0 && echo "Status not eq 0"
echo "(B) Exit code for "$status" = $?"
```

with the output:

```
(B) Exit code for 0 = 1
```

Following previous reasoning the `test` should return non zero therefore an expression after `&&` should not be executed (and it is not) but the script executes even the `test` returned non zero exit code (B) Exit code for 0 = **1**.

Why does the script continue execution? It should brake due to non zero exit status.

There is no output for the case:

```
status=0
test "$status" -ne 0
echo "(D) Exit code for "$status" = $?"
```

that suggests to me the script execution was terminated at the line `test "$status" -ne 0` and if you run `echo $?` after running the script you'll get in fact `1`.

But how come the script is terminated when the test returns non zero exit status for the example **(D)** but it is not for the example **(B)**?

The only difference between **(D)** and **(B)** is that **(B)** has `&& echo "Status not eq 0"` after the test but that is not executed and the exit status is `1` so in case of **(B)** the script should be terminated but it wasn't and if an exit status of a test is treated somehow so specially so it does not terminate a script having a `set -e` then why it terminates script for the **(D)** example?

EDIT

Similarly to `test` behaves `ls`

for the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

ls notexitingfile && echo "File exists"
echo "Exit code for ls = $?"

ls notexitingfile
echo "Exit code for ls = $?"
```

the output is:

```
ls: cannot access 'notexitingfile': No such file or directory
Exit code for ls = 2
ls: cannot access 'notexitingfile': No such file or directory
```

note `Exit code for ls = 2` for the first example and lack of it for the second.

I think the cause of the unexpected behavior may be my misunderstanding of the script termination (`set -e`) due to non zero exit code when using `&&` operator.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set -e option applies only to a single command.
It does not apply for commands combined with || or &&.

man bash says:

The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or  until  keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.

Comment: That would explain a lot, could you please give a link to any documentation that states that?

Comment: Is it possible to make set -e applying despite `&&` or `||`? Perhaps there is another option I can use instead to achieve breaking script execution even when multiple commands are combined by using `&&` or `||`?

Comment: I edited the reply with a citation from bash (which actually fixes an inaccuracy in my previous claim).

Comment: No, I do not think that there is an option to deal with && or ||.

Comment: The whole point of `&&` and `||` is to *react* to a failure in a more meaningful way than to abort the script.